# Application write in file from webapp tomcat7

Tags: java, file, tomcat7, printwriter

Please, when i deploy an application in tomcat7/webapp/myapp.war and run this application through web browser, i don't find the output file.

My application stock some result in file like this:

```
try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/user/Desktop/myfile.txt", true)));
            out.println("some text");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }
```

Where is the output file ?

Comment: Atleast in the above code I see that you are catching the IOException and silently ignoring it. If there any exception while opening or writing to file (permissions, non existing etc) you won't get to know about it. Can you add e.printStackTrace() in catch block and check the tomcat logs to see if it is throwing any file related exception.

Answer (score 1):

It will created under webapps directory i.e. myapp/home/user/Desktop/myfile.txt

Comment: euuh i don't found it. How can i Write it in my local desktop !?

Comment: try to this code PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file:/home/user/Desktop/myfile.txt", true)));

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on your desktop you need to put a forward slash (/) in front of home like so

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/user/Desktop/myfile.txt", true)));
```

Update - Try

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)));
```

then check .../tomcat/bin/ directory and have a look?

Update

Ok Try this and check your Desktop. Just tried it myself and it works for me.

```
try {
        File file = new File("/home/user/Desktop/myfile.txt");
      // creates the file
      file.createNewFile();
      // creates a FileWriter Object
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
      // Writes the content to the file
      writer.write("This\n is\n an\n example\n"); 
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }
```

Comment: Sorry i update my question. I did it with slash (/) and i don't found it !